# install ROS on ubuntu 16.04 with python3

Tags: ros, python3, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I install ROS (kinetic) with python3 support in ubuntu 16.04?

I am following the instructions at http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Source, but replacing python-* with python3-*. There is an issue with installing python3-rosinstaller-generator. The following error is generated:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
python3-rosinstall-generator : Depends: python3-distribute but it is not installable
Depends: python3-argparse but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Where can I find python3-argparse? As far as I know argparse is part of python3 by default.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240710/install-ros-on-ubuntu-16.04-with-python3/) by [Pieter](https://answers.ros.org/users/27641/pieter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-07-29

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zishan](https://answers.ros.org/users/32499/zishan/) on 2017-12-20**:
Same  issue here.Did you  manage to find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

python3-rosinstall-generator doesn't have a dependency declared on pyhon3-argparse: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosinstall_generator/blob/master/stdeb.cfg#L3  I also verified it's not in the dependencies in the repository either: http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages

Presumably this was resolved since you tried using it. However I don't ever see the dependency there since you asked the question.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1